# Slicing a scipy sparse matrix using a boolean mask

Tags: python, scipy, slice, sparse-matrix

I have encountered a difference in how slicing a scipy sparse matrix works in 0.10.0 and 0.10.1. Consider the following piece of code:

```
from numpy import array, ravel
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

mat = csr_matrix(array([[1, 0, 0], [0,1,0], [1,0,0]]))
desired_cols = ravel(mat.sum(0)) > 0

print mat[:, desired_cols].A
```

In scipy 0.10.0, I get what I expect to get:

```
[[1 0]
 [0 1]
 [1 0]]
```

In 0.10.1 and 0.12.0, I get

```
[[0 0 1]
 [1 1 0]
 [0 0 1]]
```

I am not sure if this is a bug or I am doing something wrong. I get the same results using `coo_matrix` and `csc_matrix`.

I am trying to remove all rows that sum to 0 from the matrix. I understand that `csr_matrix` does not support efficient column slicing and I should not being this.

Comment: what is `desired_cols` in these cases.  In recent scipy (0.13.0) the results match your first one (0.10.0).  You may have to dig into the github source for scipy if you want to track down changes this far back in the versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is desired_cols in these cases. In recent scipy (0.13.0) the results match your first one (0.10.0). You may have to dig into the github source for scipy if you want to track down changes this far back in the versions.

Comment: The value of `desired_cols` is `array([ True, True, False], dtype=bool)`. The problem is resolved by upgrading to scipy 0.13.0.

Answer (score 1):

Use `np.flatnonzero(desired_cols)` instead of `desired_cols` and `scipy.sparse` will support it. Full matrix API support is unavailable in `scipy.sparse` and features are gradually being introduced.