# Sklearn CountVectorizer get most frequently occurring features by class

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

I'm using CountVectorizer to convert an array of obs to a documentXfeature matrix where each document is one of  ~50 different classes. For each class, I'd like to see the most frequently occurring features.

```
cv = CountVectorizer(binary=True, tokenizer=lambda x: x.split())

# document X feature sparse matrix
vectored_sites = cv.fit_transform([' '.join([f for f in generator_features(site)]) for site in sites])

# list of classes
document_classes = [site.class for site in sites]

# how to select rows from vectored_sites for each class
class_i_document_features = ??

# compute frequency of each column in class_i_document_features
feature_counts = class_i_document_features.sum(axis=0)
feature_frequencies = feature_counts/class_i_document_features.size()[0]
# print something like (feature1: frequency1, feature2: frequency2 ...}
```

I'm having trouble with filtering to a single class and then formatting the frequencyies into a legible result.

Answer (score 0):

I would group them like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

# how to select rows from vectored_sites for each class
class_i_document_features = defaultdict(list)
for site, vector in zip(sites, vectored_sites):
    class_i_document_features[site.class].append(vector)
```

Is that what you were trying yo do?

Comment: I think I'd prefer to use a mask on vectored_sites than python lists as performance is much better. Problem is if I create a mask of with the same length as vectored_sites has rows (documents) with True for documents that are part of class i, the result vectored_sites[class_mask, :] has the same shape as vectored_sites even though only a fraction of class_mask has true values

Comment: @TedTomlinson in that case, you could try to use a [scipy sparse matrices](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.csr_matrix)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I ran into an issue with scipy sparse matrixes not supporting mask indexing in version 0.11.0 outline here: [Slicing a scipy sparse matrix using a boolean mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20080332/slicing-a-scipy-sparse-matrix-using-a-boolean-mask). Given that I switched to element index based indexes and got the solution posted below

```
# this would be in a for loop by class name
class_i = 'someclass'
class_i_indexes = [i for i in xrange(len(sites)) if sites[i].class == class_i]
for word, total in sorted(zip(cv.get_feature_names(),
                              np.asarray(vectored_sites[class_i_indexes].sum(axis=0)).ravel()),
                          key=lambda x: -x[1])[:10]:
    print '%s: %d %f' % (word, total, float(total)/len(class_i_indexes))
```

Comment: The problem in the question you link to was a bug in `scipy` that has been addressed since: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/3087